# SQL - Select all rows that have the same Email but different Name

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, duplicates

I'm trying to select all the users in a table that have the same `Email` but have a different `Name`. So far I have managed to get all the rows that have duplicate `Email` but I'm stuck on the next step.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email IN
(SELECT Email FROM users GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO What's the issue ?

Comment: And your RDBMS is – ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want `count(distinct name)` in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE Email IN (SELECT Email
                FROM users
                GROUP BY Email
                HAVING COUNT(distinct Name) > 1
               ) ;
```

I prefer `having min(name) <> max(name)` for the `having` clause.  It is slightly more efficient.

However, the most efficient method is probably to use window functions:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, min(name) over (partition by email) as minname,
             max(name) over partition by email) as maxname
      from users u
     ) u
where minname <> maxname;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM users U1
INNER JOIN 
users U2
on U1.Email=U2.Email
AND U1.Name <> U2.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Email  
   FROM users
   GROUP BY Email 
   HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT name)
) tmp ON u.Email = tmp.Email
WHERE tmp.Email IS NOT NULL
```